# Retrofit2 how to parse xml with inline tags

Tags: android, xml-parsing, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit2 and simple xml parser to parse xml value to class.

But, I'v never encountered these inline(?) tags. The api returns something, but the response's body is null.

The xml looks as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Book title="Title Name" ver="20190513001" coverimg="PPO01.jpg" bookcode="PPO01">
    <chapters count="1">
        <chapter endflag="000" thumbnail="PPO0101_TN.jpg" chaptercode="PPO0101" num="1">
        <chaptername>ChapterName</chaptername>

        <movies count="1">

            <movie num="1" name="Movie Name" url="Some Url" type="AR">
                <directions count="0"/>

            </movie>
        </movies>
    </chapter>
</chapters>
</Book>
```

My response code for this looks like.

The root object.

```
@Root(name = "Book", strict = false)
public class XmlBook implements Serializable {

    @Element(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Element(name = "ver")
    private String ver;

    @Element(name = "coverimg")
    private String coverimg;

    @Element(name = "bookcode")
    private String bookcode;

    @Element(name = "chapters")
    private XmlChapterHeader chapters;
}
```

The 'chapters' object.

```
@Root(name = "chapters", strict = false)
public class XmlChapterHeader {

    @Element(name = "count")
    private int count;

    @ElementList(name = "chapter", inline = true)
    private List<XmlChapter> chapter;

}
```

The 'chapter' object.

```
@Root(name = "chapter", strict = false)
public class XmlChapter {

    @Element(name = "num")
    private String num;

    @Element(name = "chaptercode")
    private String chaptercode;

    @Element(name = "thumbnail")
    private String thumbnail;

    @Element(name = "endflag")
    private String endflag;


    @Element(name = "chaptername")
    private String chaptername;


    @Element(name = "movies")
    private XmlMovieContainer movies;
}
```

The 'movies' object.

```
@Root(name = "movies", strict = false)
public class XmlMovieContainer {

    @ElementList(name = "movies", inline = true)
    List<XmlMovie> movie;
}
```

Finally, the 'movie' object
.

```
@Root(name = "movie", strict = false)
public class XmlMovie {

    @Element(name = "directions")
    private int directions;
}
```

I've searched on google about this issue, but I can't find a valid solution to it. Help please!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest [TikXml](https://github.com/Tickaroo/tikxml) for xml parsing because it's more easy to use and very fast compare with other xml parsers.

you have to add gradle plugins for tikxml

```
implementation 'com.tickaroo.tikxml:annotation:0.8.13'
implementation 'com.tickaroo.tikxml:core:0.8.13'
implementation 'com.tickaroo.tikxml:retrofit-converter:0.8.13'
```

**Retrofit configuration:**

```
TikXml tikxml = new TikXml.Builder().exceptionOnUnreadXml(false).build();
Retrofit retrofit =new  Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("base url")
                .addConverterFactory(TikXmlConverterFactory.create(tikxml))
                .build();
```

you have to create pojo classes with tikxml annotations

```
import com.tickaroo.tikxml.annotation.Attribute;
import com.tickaroo.tikxml.annotation.PropertyElement;
import com.tickaroo.tikxml.annotation.Xml;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;

import java.util.List;

@Xml
public class XmlBook {
    @Attribute(name = "title")
    String title;

    @Attribute(name = "ver")
    String ver;

    @Attribute(name = "coverimg")
    String coverimg;

    @Attribute(name = "bookcode")
    String bookcode;


    @Element(name = "chapters")
    Chapters chapters;
}
    @Xml
    public class Chapters {

        @Attribute(name = "count")
        String count;

        List<Chapter> chapters;

    }

    @Xml(name = "chapter")
    class Chapter {
        @PropertyElement(name = "chaptername")
        String chaptername;

        // ....
}
```

Comment: It's will really work because I used my existing projects,

Comment: I need to add these following to generate the TypeAdapter

'com.github.Tickaroo.tikxml:processor-common:0.8.15'
'com.github.Tickaroo.tikxml:processor:0.8.15'

Answer (score 0):

I think you should know the difference between 'XML element' and 'XML attribute'.

http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php